# Drush on Windows trouble

Tags: 7, drush

I had installed [Drush for Windows](http://drush.ws/drush_windows_installer) and trying use it.

I open directory (in CLI, in my example: `Z:\home\www\drush-test`) where I want install drupal and run `drush dl` command:

```
Z:\home\drush-test\www>drush dl
Install location Z:/drush/drupal-7.25 already exists. Do you want to overwrite it? (y/n):
```

But i need install drupal to `Z:\home\drush-test\www` **not** `Z:/drush/drupal-7.25` (this directory where Drush installed)

Also I trying using `drush status` in my old project (drupal installed). Drush don't see my drupal:

```
Z:\home\comp\www>drush status
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

 PHP executable        :  php.exe
 PHP configuration     :  Z:\usr\local\php5\php.ini
 PHP OS                :  WINNT
 Drush version         :  7.0-dev
 Drush configuration   :
 Drush alias files     :


Z:\home\comp\www>ls
CHANGELOG.txt       LICENSE.txt      cron.php     nbproject   update.php
COPYRIGHT.txt       MAINTAINERS.txt  includes     profiles    web.config
INSTALL.mysql.txt   README.txt       index.php    robots.txt  xmlrpc.php
INSTALL.pgsql.txt   UPGRADE.txt      install.php  scripts
INSTALL.sqlite.txt  __files          misc         sites
INSTALL.txt         authorize.php    modules      themes

Z:\home\comp\www>
```

(Drupal 7 installed in this directory)

Windows 8.1, PHP 5.3

Comment: It seems you have two separate problems, one being regarding status, and one regarding pm-download (dl). Please ask two separate questions. Also your title suggests the problem is windows related, but from the question I see no reason to believe it would be.

Comment: I think Drush for some reason can't see other directories apart from its directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Drush for Windows fix this problem.